# C Structure Problems

Tags: c, web, struct

This is a part of a web search engine I am working on. Basically I'm trying to store all the words found on an indexed URL and also the count of how many times the word occurred. Naturally I made a structure to store those two things. In the function indexMyStuff I malloc space for the structure and it's contents. I then proceed to pass it to printTrieContents, which take care of adding the data to the Structure. I am getting these errors: I'm only including these two functions to avoid a crazy lengthy post.

```
aldrbw01@timber:~/project5$ make
gcc -g -c indexPage.c -o indexPage.o
In file included from indexPage.c:12:
indexPage.h:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
indexPage.c:77: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
indexPage.c: In function ‘indexMyStuff’:
indexPage.c:147: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
indexPage.c:148: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
indexPage.c:152: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
indexPage.c: At top level:
indexPage.c:263: error: conflicting types for ‘printTrieContents’
indexPage.c:151: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘printTrieContents’ was here
indexPage.c: In function ‘printTrieContents’:
indexPage.c:291: error: too few arguments to function ‘printTrieContents’
make: *** [indexPage.o] Error 1
```

```
typedef struct wordControl queryHelper;
struct wordControl{
    char** words;
    int* countArry;
 };

 queryHelper *indexMyStuff(char* argv) {



   struct queryHelper *myStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct wordControl)*1); 
    myStruct->words=malloc(sizeof(char*)*100);
    myStruct->countArry=malloc(sizeof(int)*100);

    trieIndex_t *myTrie = indexPage(argv);
    printTrieContents(myTrie, "",myStruct);
    return freeTrieMemory(myTrie);


 }

 queryHelper *printTrieContents(trieIndex_t *pNode, char oldBuffer[MAX_WORD_SIZE],  queryHelper *structure) {
 // Alphabet counter
  int i = 0;
  // The new buffer that contains the concatenated string
  char newBuffer[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

  // Now, lets step through each of the characters. It is worthy to note that this
  // will work in alphabetical order, since the code starts counting from 0-25, and
  // each letter is stored in the character array as a mapping from a = 0 to z = 25,
  // this will automatically display them in aplhabetical order.
  for ( i = 0; i < ALPHA_SIZE; i++ ) {
  // Check if the ith character is not null
  if ( pNode->children[i] != NULL ) {

  // Now we concatenate the character at the end of the existing string
  snprintf(newBuffer, MAX_WORD_SIZE, "%s%c", oldBuffer, intToAlpha(i) );

  // If the current string is actually a word that was found in the indexing
  // process, we will print it here, as well as the amount of times that the
  // indexing function found the word.
  if ( pNode->children[i]->count > 0 ) {
  structure->words[i]=newBuffer;
  structure->countArry[i]=pNode->children[i]->count;

  }

  // Recurse through all the characters until we reach the leaves of every
  // one of the branches.
  printTrieContents( pNode->children[i], newBuffer );

   }
 }
return structure;
}





  //-----------------------------HEADER FILE--------------------------------------//
  #ifndef INDEX_H
  #define INDEX_H
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  queryHelper *indexMyStuff(char* argv);
  #endif
```

Comment: initial compiler errors are in indexPage.h. Please supply this file and make clear how it is included/

Comment: I just included it at the bottom.

Comment: Ask yourself how the compiler knows what a `queryHelper` is when compiling your header *before* any definition is provided for that id?

Answer (score 1):

```
indexPage.h:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

Look at that line:

```
queryHelper *indexMyStuff(char* argv);
```

What's queryHelper? The compiler has no idea. It's a bad message for the error but it's because the compiler doesn't know what type it is. You need to move the typedef to the header (above that line).

And the next error:

```
indexPage.c:77: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

You didn't include that line (or tell us which it is), so we can't help you on that

```
indexPage.c: In function ‘indexMyStuff’:
indexPage.c:147: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
indexPage.c:148: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
indexPage.c:152: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

on

```
struct queryHelper *myStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct wordControl)*1); 
myStruct->words=malloc(sizeof(char*)*100);
myStruct->countArry=malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

Don't add `struct`.